# How do I configure the INSERT INTO connection details to ingest a csv from EC2 to an AWS RDS MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, sql-insert

I have a 70Mb csv with 1.5 million rows with 270 columns and I would like to put it into a MySQL database that is hosted on AWS RDS with the minimum layer. I try to do it with the MySQL Workbench widget. But it took me 1 hour to ingest 100 lines. So it will take me 2 years if I do it this way. Do you know another way to efficiently ingest a CSV on a MySQL instance hosted on AWS?

I tried to do it with an EC2. I have transferred the file on the machine but how to transfer it to RDS? How will it give the connection information?  Everything that I found seems to be for local databases:

```
load data local infile 'results_women.csv' into table table
 fields terminated by ','
 enclosed by '"'
 lines terminated by '\n'
 (column1, column2, column3,...)
```

I am now trying with mysqlimport thanks to the tips of Alex but I don't have it (yet)

```
 mysqlimport: command not found
```

I tried to install it but it seems to be complicated:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-193 ~]$ sudo yum install mysqlimport
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00
amzn2extra-docker                                        | 3.0 kB     00:00
amzn2extra-kernel-5.10                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
No package mysqlimport available.
```

So I tried to do it locally but it seems it couldn't find the database:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\RDSCode>  mysqlimport --local     
      --compress     
      --user=admin     
      --password=hahahahaah     
      --host=women-poc.hohohoho.here-there-3.rds.amazonaws.com     
      --fields-terminated-by=',' 
      firmenich.results_women 
      results_women*                                                                      
      
mysqlimport: mysqlimport: Error: 1049 Unknown database 'firmenich.results_women'
```

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html) recommends using [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html). Have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AlexBrohshtut Yes, unfortunately I doesn't have it on my ec2 instance. I tried to yum install it but it says `command not found`.